# Django ListView how to make query I need in class as I had it before in my function

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm new at django and did my first project using book Eric Matthews python crash course, but now I'm trying do it better and change function that works perfectly into class, but can not get how to make it in Class the same query by filtering public and not public "topics" for users. Could somebody give me advice please how it works in classes?

The function which is works perfectly and then the class I need worked like this function:

```
 def topics(request):
 """Provide list of topics."""
    public_topics = Topic.objects.filter(public=True).order_by('date_added')
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        private_topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by('date_added')
        topics = public_topics | private_topics
    else:
        topics = public_topics

    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)
```

And there is the class I need that it worked like the previous function. Could you advice what should be in queryset with public, owner and request?

```
class TopicsHome(ListView):

    model = Topic

    template_name = 'learning_logs/topics.html'

    context_object_name = 'topics'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Topic.objects.filter(public=True).order_by('date_added')
```

Finally I did it with advice of @Avinash Raj, thank you!) but code seems bigger with classes)) I was thinking it will be easier in classes. Is it fine or is there some better way to realize this via classes?

```
class TopicsHome(ListView):
    model = Topic
    template_name = 'learning_logs/topics.html'
    context_object_name = 'topics'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        public_topics = Topic.objects.filter(public=True).order_by('date_added')
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            private_topics = Topic.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user).order_by('date_added')
            topics = public_topics | private_topics
        else:
            topics = public_topics
        return topics
```

I found the solution, it should be some kind of this, but need to understand what filter should I use

```
class ShowTopic(DetailView):
    model = Topic
    template_name = 'learning_logs/topic.html'
    context_object_name = 'topic'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'topic_slug'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ShowTopic, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['entries'] = Entry.objects.all()
        return context
```

Comment: you can access request object on get_queryset method using `self.request`

Comment: Thanks ! ) It works, but finally code of Class seems more bigger, is it fine?) I was thinking using of Classes made code more understandable and decrease amount of lines, or this connected only with my case and this filter?

Comment: It is totally fine, there will be seperate method for handling each type of request in classes but on functions it will be many if else stmts.

Comment: I found the solution I think, not at all, but already close to it) I added the new edit with the current state of code